# Freezing certain layers in neural networks using Pytorch Image Models

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, transfer-learning, image-classification

I am trying to do binary classification using transfer learning using [Timm](https://github.com/rwightman/pytorch-image-models)

In the process, I want to experiment with freezing/unfreezing different layers of different architectures but so far, I am able to freeze/unfreeze entire models only.
Can anyone help me in illustrating it with a couple of model architectures for the sake of heterogeneity of different architectures?
Below, I am ilustrating the entire freezing of couple of architectures using Timm - convnext and resnet but can anyone illustrate me with any different models but only using Timm(As it is more comprehensive than Pytorch model zoo)-

```
import timm
convnext = timm.create_model('convnext_tiny_in22k', pretrained=True,num_classes=2) 
resnet = timm.create_model('resnet50d', pretrained=True,num_classes=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it:

```
import timm
model = timm.create_model('resnet50', pretrained=True, num_classes=2)
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    if name == 'conv1.weight' or name == 'bn1.weight' or name == 'bn1.bias':
        param.requires_grad = False
    if 'layer1' in name:
        param.requires_grad = False
    print(name, param.requires_grad)
```

In the above code, I froze the weights of the first layer (out of four).
There is a thin convolution layer in the input, which is why I freeze it separately.

In general, when you print the model, you can see the names of the layers.
Then you can set `.requires_grad=True` or `.requires_grad=False` for each layer depending on your use case.